# How do I write an ansible handler that can run a task on failure?

Tags: ansible, handler

I want to use ansible 2.5.2 to perform some upgrade tasks and rollback to a previous install if they fail. I use notify on all config changes to prevent an upgrade if there are no changes. I initially thought to use `block:` and `rescue:` statements in the handler for that notify.

However as this is not supported yet (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14270) I instead took the suggested workaround of including another task in the notify block, to end up with something equivalent to the following:

```
upgrade
|-handlers
  main.yml
  - name: upgrade task
    include: upgrade.yml
|-tasks
  main.yml
  - name: Update configuration 1
    template: src=conf.j2 dest={{ conf_dir }}/conf.conf
    notify: upgrade task
  - name: Update configuration 2
    template: src=conf2.j2 dest={{ conf_dir }}/conf2.conf
    notify: upgrade task

  upgrade.yml
  - block:
    - debug: msg="Starting upgrade"
    - name: Simulate failure of first of many upgrade tasks
      command: /bin/false
    rescue:
    - debug: msg="Upgrade failed, rolling back now"
    - name: Rollback deploy
      include: rollback.yml
    always:
    - debug: msg="Upgrade complete"

  rollback.yml
    ....
```

As expected this fails on:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [upgrade : Simulate failure of first of many upgrade tasks] 
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED!
```

but no `Upgrade failed` or `Upgrade complete` is printed and the `rollback.yml` is not executed.

The possibilities seems to be:

1. There is an error in my tasks that is silently preventing the rescue block from running.
2. There is an ansible bug which has not been raised yet with blocks in included plays.
3. What I am trying to do is not supported.

Can anyone spot an issue or give me some pointers on structuring this problem in a supported way? The only alternative I can think of is using a `listen` to group the handlers, mark them as changed but not failed when they fail, and have them notify the rollback task, but at first glance this seems like it would be extremely fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be both 2. and 3. If the example block is moved into main.yml, it functions perfectly, ruling out 1.

In the comments of the feature request I linked in my question, another person mentions having the same issue back in 2016, so I have now raised a new bug: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/40130

To answer the question about a better alternative to the very hacky workaround for a workaround I suggested, it is possible to use `register:` as a conditional to allow the block to be moved into `tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: Update configuration 1
  template: src=conf.j2 dest={{ conf_dir }}/conf.conf
  register: update1

- name: Update configuration 2
  template: src=conf2.j2 dest={{ conf_dir }}/conf2.conf
  register: update2

- block:
  - debug: msg="Starting upgrade"
    when: update1.changed or update2.changed

  - name: Simulate failure of first of many upgrade tasks
    command: /bin/false
    when: update1.changed or update2.changed

  rescue:
  - debug: msg="Upgrade failed, rolling back now"

  - name: Rollback deploy
    include: rollback.yml

  always:
  - debug: msg="Upgrade complete"
```

This is still fragile as you need to remember to update everything in the block every time a configuration task is added. If you are OK with manually flushing handlers, the following approach removes that concern and is a bit cleaner IMHO:

```
- name: Update configuration 1
  template: src=conf.j2 dest={{ conf_dir }}/conf.conf
  notify: trigger upgrade

- name: Update configuration 2
  template: src=conf2.j2 dest={{ conf_dir }}/conf2.conf
  notify: trigger upgrade

- meta: flush_handlers

- block:
  - debug: msg="Starting upgrade"
    when: upgrade is defined and upgrade.changed
    ...
```

where `trigger upgrade` is a handler in `handlers/main.yml` that makes a dummy change, i.e.:

```
- name: trigger upgrade
  shell: echo "Upgrading"
  register: upgrade
```

I think this is the best that can be done until the bug is fixed or blocks are allowed in handlers.